# Scrapy crawlSpider rules - prioritize "next pages"

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

Im trying to scrape a list of all the hotels in San Francisco from:
http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60713-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html

the "Next Hotels" has unique urls:

page 2 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa30-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html

page 3 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa60-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html

page 4 is: /Hotels-g60713-oa90-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html

and so on..

1. How can I set the crawlSpider to reach these pages
2. Is there a Rule that can help me in this case?
3. Is there a way to prioritize and make it scrape and parse these pages before anything else?

my code so far:

import beatSoup_test
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

```
class TriAdvSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "tripAdv"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60713-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html"
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'-\w+.html$'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        beatSoup_test.getHotels(response.body_as_unicode())
```

where beatSoup_test is my parsing function that uses beautifulsoup.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrape the data from any page. Use [Xpath](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)
That way you can scrape anything at same page.

And Use items to store the scraped data so that u can scrape as many thing you want.

Here is example how you can use it.

```
sites = Selector(text=response.body).xpath('//div[contains(@id, "identity")]//section/div/div/h3/a/text()')
    items = []
    items = myspiderBotItem()
    items['title'] = sites.xpath('/text()').extract()
```

Like this

```
class TriAdvSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "tripAdv"
    allowed_domains = ["tripadvisor.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g60713-San_Francisco_California-Hotels.html"
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'-\w+.html$'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):
        # beatSoup_test.getHotels(response.body_as_unicode())
        l = XPathItemLoader(item = TriAdvItem(),response = response)
        for i in range(1,8):

            l.add_xpath('day','//*[@id="super-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/th[@scope="row"]/text()')
            l.add_xpath('timings1','//*[@id="super-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/span[1]/text()')
            l.add_xpath('timings2','//*[@id="super-container"]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]/span[2]/text()')
        return l.load_item()
```